# resource cannot be found for calling back to HttpPost method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project. My site connect to bank gateway and after successfull payment, the results POST to my website to run VerifyPayment method (this method is of type HttpPost).

```
 [HttpPost]
   // [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult VerifyPayment( VerifyResult Vresult )
    {
        try
        {
            // var transact = Request.Form["transId"];
            // TempData["msg"] = $"<script>alert('transaction id is: {transact}');</script>";
            //// for test
            // return View(new VerifyResult() { success = true, SuccessMessage = "nice", Amount = "20000" });
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["transId"]) )
            {
                Payment ob = new Payment();
                string result = ob.verify(Request.Form["transId"].ToString());
                JsonParameters Parmeters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonParameters>(result);

                if ( Parmeters.status == 1 )
                {
                    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
                    user.SuccessfullPayment = true;
                    user.FactorNo = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    user.TraceNo = Request.Form["traceNumber"];
                    user.TransId = int.Parse(Request.Form["transId"]);
                    user.CardNo = Request.Form["cardNumber"];
                    user.PurchasedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    user.State = Parmeters.status;
                    user.Message = Request.Form["message"];
                    db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    Vresult.success = true;
                    Vresult.TransActionID += Request.Form["transId"].ToString();
                    Vresult.Amount += Parmeters.amount.ToString();
                    Vresult.SuccessMessage = "پرداخت با موفقیت انجام شد.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "DownloadEbook");
                }
                else
                {

                    Vresult.error = true;
                    Vresult.ErrorMessage = "کدخطا : " + Parmeters.errorCode + "<br />" + "پیغام خطا : " + Parmeters.errorMessage;

                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            Vresult.error = true;
            Vresult.ErrorMessage = "متاسفانه پرداخت ناموفق بوده است.";
        }

        return View(new AllNeededModels() { VerifyResult = Vresult });
    }
```

VerifyPayment method has its own View.cshtml file called "VerifyPayment.cshtml".

```
@model Mahdavimanesh.Models.AllNeededModels
@{
   ViewBag.Title = " ";
   }

       <div class="container">
          @if (Model.VerifyResult.success)
              {
     <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-lg-6 center-block" style="float: none;">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" 
          Text=""></asp:Label>
                @Model.VerifyResult.SuccessMessage
                <br />
                  : @Model.VerifyResult.TransActionID
                <br />
                 : @(Model.VerifyResult.Amount)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
             }

         else

           {


             <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 center-block" style="float: none;">
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  @Model.VerifyResult.ErrorMessage
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>


            }

        </div>
```

Everything works correctly on my localhost. However, when I publish the website, after successful payment and calling back to my website, it notifies me the error of "Resource Cannot be Found". I think the problem is raised because of HttpPost VerifyMethod, and that VerifyPayment.cshtml is for HttpGet method. if this, why it works on my local machine?

Is there any clue?

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "DownloadEbook");` verify that a view exists and that you are also passing the correct action and controller name

Comment: all of them exist.

Comment: What are the full details of the error message? (and a `.cshtml` file has nothing to do with it being a GET or POST)

Comment: full error message: " The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /HelpMeToBuildMyExtraordinaryYear/VerifyPayment "